# How to find out size of the individual databases in the sql server 2005?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Please tell the query to find out size of the individual databases in the sql server 2005?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this [sp_spaceused](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx)

```
exec sp_spaceused
```

Comment: Thanks I executed and i got the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'EXEC sp_spaceused [?]'
```