# how to find out log size of each of the database in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

**Duplicate of: [How to find out size of the individual databases in the sql server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496136/how-to-find-out-size-of-the-individual-databases-in-the-sql-server-2005)**

how to find out log size of each of the database in sql server 2005?

Comment: can any one provide me a solution.
I will be clear this time if A,B are the databases in my Server.
I want log size of database A,Log size of database B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this SQL:

```
EXECUTE sp_msforeachdb 'SELECT *, GETDATE() FROM [?].sys.database_files'
```

Comment: Hi Orban here i am not getting log file size of database at once.
<br>I want like for example A,B are databases in the server then <br>I want total log size of A,Total log size of server B.Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: Your question sepcified "each database", that is what the above does.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL management studio , goto object explorer, right click database, goto "properties" , select "Files" . These you can see one "Initial size" column which will be the size of your DB. you will get both Data and Log file size over here.

Comment: Thanks for your help Umesh.I will execute the query and i will update you.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
dbcc sqlperf(logspace)
```

Bye.

Answer (score 0):

[How to determine SQL Server database transaction log usage](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1225)

try this :

```
DBCC SQLPERF(logspace)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have rights...

```
SELECT SIZE/128.0, * FROM sys.master_files MF WHERE MF.type = 1
```